# Can I test bot made with MS Bot Framework on Skype without publishing it?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, skype, cortana

I registered my bot in the dashboard, but did not enable it on Skype or other channels, because I have login and it is just not ready yet, so it won't be secure to publish it in the bot directory and everyone tickle it. I want to test how a bot behave and looks in Skype without publishing it to Skype, because I don't like the interpretation of the Emulator in the Bot Framework. Is it possible?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure of the answer. However, I am sure that you don't have to worry about anyone tickling your bot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bot will only be abe to be added by people you share a link with.  To get to the link, go to the [dev portal](https://dev.botframework.com) and click on skype as in the screenshot

[image]

This will bring up a screen like below.  You can copy this URL to share your bot with others, or just click the **Add to Contacts** button to add it yourself.

[image]

To add your bot to be visible for search you must first publish your bot by clicking edit for the skype channel in the [dev portal](https://dev.botframework.com)

[image]

then click on publish

[image]

at the bottom of this page you can choose to add your bot to search or not.

[image]

Your bot will have to be approved before others will see it

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your bot will only be visible in Skype to those who have the 'add contact' link, don't worry.
Same for Facebook Messenger channel, only accredited users can get conversations with the bot.

Comment: Then at what point it becomes visible in the Skype bot directory via the search box?

Comment: Jason brought the complete answer: your bot will be listed once published and validated